# PHP Oracle convert date to mm/dd/yyyy from yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am displaying a date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
select id,notes,TO_CHAR(arrival_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') requested_date
from orders where id = 51;
```

Users change the date with a javascript pop-up calendar, then submit changes.

```
update orders
set arrival_date = to_date('2015-02-10','mm/dd/yyyy')
where id='51';
```

I replaced `$requested_date` with `'2015-02-10'` to test in Toad and got

> ORA-(01843)not a valid month

My arrival_date is a `DATE` type.

Comment: Err, you're telling it to use `mm/dd/yyyy` format in `to_date()` yet passing a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the format..   You pass `2015-02-10` for format `mm/dd/yyyy` that can't work. Instead use :

```
to_date('02/10/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Sorry.  I just realized the format is for my input date, and not the format I want to enter to the database.  So I don't need to worry about what format I input to the database, since it's a DATE type.  I can just update it using
date'$arrival_date'